# Duplicating entries on C# list

Tags: c#, list, duplicates

I'm a little new to C# and I'm having a weird issue.
What's happening is that all the values that I'm adding to a List are getting duplicated and I don't know why because everytime I add a object to the list, I reinitialize that object on the following line... Here's my code:

```
waves=new List<EnemyWave>();
EnemyWave cur_wave=null;
for (int i=1; i<lines.Length; i++){
    string[] point_b=lines[i].Split("\t"[0]);
    if (point_b[0].StartsWith("[WAVE ")){
        string wave_data=point_b[0].Replace("[WAVE ","");
        int data=System.Convert.ToInt32(wave_data.Remove(wave_data.Length-1));
        if (cur_wave==null){
            cur_wave=new EnemyWave(data);
            path.addPoint(System.Convert.ToInt32(point_a[0]),System.Convert.ToInt32(point_a[1]));
        } else {
            waves.Add(cur_wave);
            cur_wave=new EnemyWave(data);
        }
    } else {
        if (cur_wave==null){
            createPath(point_a,point_b,i);
            point_a=point_b;
        } else {
            string type=point_b[0].ToLower();
            int wait_time=0;
            if (point_b.Length>1 && !point_b[1].Equals("")){
                wait_time=System.Convert.ToInt32(point_b[1]);
            }
            cur_wave.addEnemyData(type,wait_time);
        }
    }
}
waves.Add(cur_wave);
```

So, what is important here is `waves` and `cur_wave` and, as you see, after I add `cur_wave` to `waves`, I reinitialize it. So, what else is making the duplicates? Because I put a debug code before and after the `waves.Add(cur_wave); cur_wave=new EnemyWave(data);` lines and on the first debug, I get the items of position `0` correct but, on the second debug code, the items of positions `0` have been cleared...

**EDIT**

I forgot to say that I'm using Unity 4.2.2f1. Here's my debug code:

```
[...]
if (point_b[0].StartsWith("[WAVE ")){
    string wave_data=point_b[0].Replace("[WAVE ","");
    int data=System.Convert.ToInt32(wave_data.Remove(wave_data.Length-1));
    if (cur_wave==null){
        cur_wave=new EnemyWave(data);
        path.addPoint(System.Convert.ToInt32(point_a[0]),System.Convert.ToInt32(point_a[1]));
    } else {
        if (waves.Count>0){
            foreach (EnemyData en_data in waves[0].getArrayEnemyData()){
                Debug.Log (en_data.getType());
            }
        }
        if(!waves.Contains(cur_wave)) 
            waves.Add(cur_wave);
        cur_wave=new EnemyWave(data);
        if (waves.Count>0){
            foreach (EnemyData en_data in waves[0].getArrayEnemyData()){
                Debug.Log (en_data.getType());
            }
        }
    }
} else {
[...]
```

Here's the contents of the file.

```
-320    240
-220    40
220 60
320 -240
[WAVE 1000]
Weak
Weak    500
Weak    500
Weak    1000
[WAVE 1000]
Weak    
Weak    500
Weak    500
[WAVE 1000]
Medium
Medium  500
```

Both debugs should print this:

```
weak
weak
weak
weak
```

But I'm getting on `weak` less and I only get it on the first debug... The second one is not printing anything... What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the error was not with this code... It was with `EnemyWave` and so, I was really looking on the wrong place... Here's the problem:

```
public static List<EnemyData> enemies_data;
```

Because of making this `static` by mistake, I was thinking that somehow, the object passed to the `List` was beeing duplicated... But no, I was just replacing this variable everytime I was making a `new`, without knowing it... So the solution was simply to changed this code into that:

```
private List<EnemyData> enemies_data;
```

Damn, I never had a problem like that before...

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating through a list of elements (lines of a file?), performing some modifications and adding the corresponding variables to a list without any pre-check. If the given elements are duplicated (e.g., two identical lines), they would be added to the list anyway. Also you are performing a last addition outside the loop which might be provoking a further duplication. Safest thing is checking always before adding. Replace `waves.Add(cur_wave);` with:

```
if(!waves.Contains(cur_wave)) waves.Add(cur_wave);
```

Comment: I can´t test it right now but I think that the problem is not the last line because as I said, I've put 2 debug codes (printing the contents of a variable that is inside of `waves[0]`) after and before adding the next iteration and, in the first it gave me the contents but, on the second, it gave me nothing (like the `waves[0]` have been replaced by `new EnemyWave(data);`). Also, I already checked that I don't have duplicated lines (but yes, they are from a file =) ).

Comment: @cristianosantos the modification I suggested makes sure that no repetition will occur no matter what; this the recommended proceeding for your conditions. In any case, as said, your code doesn't account for repetitions at all: the inputs are taken from the file, if it has various identical records, duplicates would appear

Comment: @varocarabs It didn't work... I will edit my question and put the code that I used to debug. Maybe it helps.

Comment: @cristianosantos (my nick is varocarbas) i will take a look at it tomorrow, now i write from my mobile. In any case there is not too much to look at: the proposed correction lets your code work as so far but avoids any IDENTICAL duplicate (logically, it does not account for caps)

Comment: Sorry for the nick =S. I know it does, but what seems to be happening is that somehow, the variable `cur_wave` is always attached to `waves[0]` even when I make a `new`... That's why I'm not understanding how it is happening.

Comment: I found the problem... What was happening is that my `EnemyWave` class had a static variable (I don't remember to put it there but, it was there...). Anyway, your answer helped me to find it and so, I will upvote you.

Comment: @CristianoSantos you are welcome. In any case, you should post all the relevant code and describe exactly the problem/add relevant inputs (to get help quickly and to allow others to benefit from the question/answer). With the information you provided, the most logical reason is having repeated records in the file (how can be the solution be something which is not referred in the question?!). While adding elements to a list (and wanting them unique) you have to check for previous occurrences (for example, via Contains as suggested).

Comment: @CristianoSantos summary: the answer to the generic question "how can I avoid repeated records in a list?" Is what I answered. The answer to the question "I have a specific situation where for some reason I cannot understand the records in a list are repeated, what might be the problem?" + all the relevant information (exact input conditions, all the relevant code (initialisation/declaration of variables, used functions/classes, etc)), in this specific case, is yours. Please, in the future, choose any of these options and post all the required information accordingly :)

Comment: Well, you right but now, I really don't know wich answer to accept, because yours are correct for the contents I put on the question and mine is correct for my case. I never had that problem before here on stackoverflow so, don't know which one is considered to be right.

Comment: @CristianoSantos choose yours. Mine has a +1 and is enough :)